# Can't send message from python server to java client

Tags: java, python, sockets, server

I try to create a client/server application between my Raspberry Pi (server in Python) and a java Client over my local network.

I can't figure out how to send message from the Python server to the Java client. I always have the error : [Errno 32] Broken pipe.

I can't seen where I'm wrong.

Here the Server code :

```
class ServerLED():
'''
classdocs
'''


def __init__(self, port = 15555):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    self.socketPi = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socketPi.bind(("", port))
    self.response = ""

def listening(self):
    self.socketPi.listen(5)
    self.client, self.address = self.socketPi.accept()
    print "{} connected".format( self.address )

def receivingMessage(self):
    self.response = self.client.recv(1024)
    if self.response != "":
            print self.response

def answer(self):
    messageTosend = "Echo \r\n"
    try:
        self.socketPi.send(messageTosend)
    except socket.error, e:
        print "error is ", e
        self.socketPi.close()
```

I use the function this way :

```
socketPi = Server.ServerLED()
print "listening..."
socketPi.listening()
print "sending message..."
socketPi.answer()
print "done"
socketPi.receivingMessage()
```

On the client side (in JAVA) :

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.18", 15555);
System.out.println("SOCKET = " + socket);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
str = in.readLine();      // Reding "ECHO"

System.out.println(str);     

out.println("Hello");          // sending message
```

I'm always stuck in the first "send()" of the server.
If I start by sending a message from the client to the server, the server reads it but fails to respond.

Server output :

```
Start python for LED
listening...
('192.168.1.13', 58774) connected
sending message...
error is  [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Does someone know where I am wrong ?
Thanks a lot.

Maxime.

Comment: I have written something similar to your python server recently and I used a python module called asynchat it was quite easy to implement. https://docs.python.org/2/library/asynchat.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a strange setup generally, but in the server you should be sending on the connection socket (self.client), not on the listening socket (self.socketPi).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the Socket you create in java isn't [`bind`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29), that is - the Socket object is just created, but not opened waiting for the raspberry pi incoming socket connection.

Add the row

```
socket.bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.18", 15555));
```

after the socket is created. The address in the `Socket` constructor is probably not nescessary.